# Daemon with Cocoa

Tags: macos, cocoa, daemon, launchd

I wrote a FTP Server, witch is started from the command line via ftpd.command.
Now I want to run that command from a Cocoa app.

I want to quit the app and the command should remain running.
And when I return to the Cocoa app, it should know, if the FTP Server is still running.

Is anybody out there who can help me?
Thanks a lot!
Julian

Answer (score 2):

You should be using `launchd` to handle the FTP server. It is specifically designed for the situation you describe, namely launching and managing background services.

You need to create a `launchd` configuration file, which can be placed in one of these locations:

- `~/Library/LaunchAgents`: Per-user agents provided by the user.
- `/Library/LaunchAgents`: Per-user agents provided by the administrator.
- `/Library/LaunchDaemons`: System-wide daemons provided by the
  administrator.

A ***daemon*** is a system-wide service of which there is one instance for all clients. An ***agent*** is a service that runs on a per-user basis.

[`launchd` Configuration files](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/launchd.plist.5.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/5/launchd.plist) are in the form of a [property list.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man5/plist.5.html)

You need to create a `launchd` configuration plist and place it in one of the above locations. You can configure the plist so that `launchd` runs your service at launch or periodically, or in response to various actions (such as the contents of a folder changing).

To check to see whether or not your job is running, you need to use the [Service Management framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Reference/ServiceManagementFwRef/ServiceManagement_h/index.html). You can ask `launchd` for the status of your job like so:

```
CFDictionaryRef jobDict = SMJobCopyDictionary(kSMDomainUserLaunchd, CFSTR("com.your.apps.bundle.id"));
```

If the job could not be found then `jobDict` will be `NULL`.

(If you're using a system-level daemon then you would replace `kSMDomainUserLaunchd` with `kSMDomainSystemLaunchd`).

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to adjust your FTP server so that it won't "block" the command line until it's finished. I have found some sample code here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void start_daemon(void)
{
    chdir("/");
    setsid();

    close(STDIN_FILENO);
    close(STDOUT_FILENO);
    close(STDERR_FILENO);

    open("/dev/null", O_RDWR);
    dup(STDIN_FILENO);
    dup(STDIN_FILENO);

    for(;;)
        sleep(100);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pid_t pid;

    if ((pid = fork()) < 0)
    {
        perror("fork() failed");
        return 1;
    }

    if (pid == 0)
        start_daemon();

    printf("Child has PID %i.\n", pid);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a decidedly non-Cocoa solution.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the source code for my project TabletMagic on GitHub. It has a Cocoa preference pane which launches a user space daemon, plus it manages a launchd item. The Cocoa portion uses an external helper to do all its privileged tasks, which is self-setuid the first time it's launched - in a privileged context by the Cocoa app asking for admin authorization. This is all standard procedure, despite not being pure Cocoa.